# Photoshop - Open random images

Tags: javascript, random, directory, photoshop

I have been looking for a script to open two random images from 2 separate folders (so one image per folder) into photoshop.

The idea being the cutout in one folder and overlay in the other

These are folders with 100's of pictures...

Any help would be much appreciated <3

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Where are you now?

Comment: To be 100% honest I couldn't script to save my life... I did python before for different reasons but thats long ago... If it would be one random image from a folder would be good already...